# Помогите сделать обзор с двух камер в three.js

Tags: three.js

Задача следующая:
Есть сцена тип ландшафта.
В ней находятся две 3D модели людей.
Как сделать, чтобы можно было смотреть на сцену с точки зрения каждого из этих людей ?

Правильно-ли я понимаю, что мне необходимо эмулировать камеру от первого лица, как в играх. Использовать FirstPersonControls ? Или можно средствами стандартного three.js поставить камеры на этих объектах и переключаться между ними ?

Comment: Чтобы избежать такого плюрализма мнений в ответах, лучше в вопрос добавлять пример в виде code snippet или на jsfiddle.

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете задавать явно позицию камеры и направление, куда она смотрит каждый раз при переключении с одного персонажа на другой

```
    //camera placed at human1's head and facing at human2
    var humanHeight = 10;
    camera.position.set(human1.matrixWorld.getPosition().x, human1.matrixWorld.getPosition().y + humanHeight, human1.matrixWorld.getPosition().z);
    camera.lookAt(human2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Был [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740076/one-scene-but-multiple-viewports-with-their-own-camera-three-js) в английской версии 
Попробуйте так: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4oL782zs/)

```js
if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats;

var views, scene, renderer;

var mesh, group1, group2, group3, light;

var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var windowWidth, windowHeight;

var views = [{
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 0.5,
    height: 1.0,
    background: new THREE.Color().setRGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.7),
    eye: [0, 300, 1800],
    up: [0, 1, 0],
    fov: 30,
    updateCamera: function(camera, scene, mouseX, mouseY) {
      camera.position.x += mouseX * 0.05;
      camera.position.x = Math.max(Math.min(camera.position.x, 2000), -2000);
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    }
  },
  {
    left: 0.5,
    top: 0.5,
    width: 0.5,
    height: 0.5,
    background: new THREE.Color().setRGB(0.7, 0.5, 0.5),
    eye: [0, 1800, 0],
    up: [0, 0, 1],
    fov: 45,
    updateCamera: function(camera, scene, mouseX, mouseY) {
      camera.position.x -= mouseX * 0.05;
      camera.position.x = Math.max(Math.min(camera.position.x, 2000), -2000);
      camera.lookAt(camera.position.clone().setY(0));
    }
  },
  {
    left: 0.5,
    top: 0,
    width: 0.5,
    height: 0.5,
    background: new THREE.Color().setRGB(0.5, 0.7, 0.7),
    eye: [1400, 800, 1400],
    up: [0, 1, 0],
    fov: 60,
    updateCamera: function(camera, scene, mouseX, mouseY) {
      camera.position.y -= mouseX * 0.05;
      camera.position.y = Math.max(Math.min(camera.position.y, 1600), -1600);
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    }
  }
];

init();
animate();

function init() {

  container = document.getElementById('container');

  for (var ii = 0; ii < views.length; ++ii) {

    var view = views[ii];
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(view.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.fromArray(view.eye);
    camera.up.fromArray(view.up);
    view.camera = camera;

  }

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  light.position.set(0, 0, 1);
  scene.add(light);

  // shadow

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 128;
  canvas.height = 128;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 0, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.width / 2);
  gradient.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.15)');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

  context.fillStyle = gradient;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var shadowTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);

  var shadowMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: shadowTexture,
    transparent: true
  });
  var shadowGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(300, 300, 1, 1);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(shadowGeo, shadowMaterial);
  mesh.position.y = -250;
  mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(mesh);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(shadowGeo, shadowMaterial);
  mesh.position.x = -400;
  mesh.position.y = -250;
  mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(mesh);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(shadowGeo, shadowMaterial);
  mesh.position.x = 400;
  mesh.position.y = -250;
  mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(mesh);

  var faceIndices = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  var color, f, f2, f3, p, vertexIndex,

    radius = 200,

    geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(radius, 1),
    geometry2 = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(radius, 1),
    geometry3 = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(radius, 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {

    f = geometry.faces[i];
    f2 = geometry2.faces[i];
    f3 = geometry3.faces[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

      vertexIndex = f[faceIndices[j]];

      p = geometry.vertices[vertexIndex];

      color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
      color.setHSL((p.y / radius + 1) / 2, 1.0, 0.5);

      f.vertexColors[j] = color;

      color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
      color.setHSL(0.0, (p.y / radius + 1) / 2, 0.5);

      f2.vertexColors[j] = color;

      color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
      color.setHSL(0.125 * vertexIndex / geometry.vertices.length, 1.0, 0.5);

      f3.vertexColors[j] = color;

    }

  }


  var materials = [

    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xffffff,
      shading: THREE.FlatShading,
      vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
      shininess: 0
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x000000,
      shading: THREE.FlatShading,
      wireframe: true,
      transparent: true
    })

  ];

  group1 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, materials);
  group1.position.x = -400;
  group1.rotation.x = -1.87;
  scene.add(group1);

  group2 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry2, materials);
  group2.position.x = 400;
  group2.rotation.x = 0;
  scene.add(group2);

  group3 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry3, materials);
  group3.position.x = 0;
  group3.rotation.x = 0;
  scene.add(group3);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  stats = new Stats();
  container.appendChild(stats.dom);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowWidth / 2);
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHeight / 2);

}

function updateSize() {

  if (windowWidth != window.innerWidth || windowHeight != window.innerHeight) {

    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    renderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  }

}

function animate() {

  render();
  stats.update();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function render() {

  updateSize();

  for (var ii = 0; ii < views.length; ++ii) {

    var view = views[ii];
    var camera = view.camera;

    view.updateCamera(camera, scene, mouseX, mouseY);

    var left = Math.floor(windowWidth * view.left);
    var top = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.top);
    var width = Math.floor(windowWidth * view.width);
    var height = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.height);

    renderer.setViewport(left, top, width, height);
    renderer.setScissor(left, top, width, height);
    renderer.setScissorTest(true);
    renderer.setClearColor(view.background);

    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

  }

}
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  color: #0080ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Я так понял, ему надо не сразу два view, а переключение позиции камеры